# How to use multiple flexslider in different events

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

I am using two flexsliders on same page but in different events. Both flexsliders works fine. But second slider has some jerk for first time when the click event triggers.

```
$('#slider').flexslider({ 
    animation: "slide", 
    easing: "swing", 
    direction: "horizontal", 
    controlNav: true,  
    asNavFor: '#slider2',
    directionNav: true
});
$('.HowItWorks').click(function(){
    $('#slider2').flexslider({ 
        animation: "slide", 
        easing: "swing", 
        direction: "horizontal", 
        controlNav: true,  
        directionNav: true ,
        sync: "#slider"
    });
})
```

Comment: Are you looking into something like this http://jsfiddle.net/BSwJn/258/

Comment: @SreekeshOkky: Exactly. Need to fix this.

Comment: I didn't get the issue. Is it that you want the slider to show smoothly? Something like http://jsfiddle.net/BSwJn/260/

Comment: @SreekeshOkky - yes, to show slider smoothly.

Comment: Does the new fiddle solve your issue?